# metric parse error: expected field at offset # is not very helpful

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I have a problem with Telegraf where it returns an error in the input when working with the following lines produced by a powershell script:

nps,Component\ Name=E\:\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Free\ -\ MB metric_value=42639.22 1546062000000000000
nps,Component\ Name=E\:\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Total\ -\ MB metric_value=140960 1546062000000000000
nps,Component\ Name=E\:\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Utilization metric_value=0.69751 1546062000000000000
nps,Component\ Name=E\:\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Used\ -\ MB metric_value=98320.77 1546062000000000000

The truncated error is:

2018-12-29T06:48:27Z E! Error in plugin [inputs.exec]: metric parse error: expected field at offset 61: 
"nps,Component Name=E: Label:DB Serial Number 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Free\ -\ MB metric_value=42639.22 1546062000000000000\nnps,Component\ Name=E\:\\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Total\ -\ MB metric_value=140960 1546062000000000000\nnps,Component\ Name=E\:\\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,Node\ Family=Microsoft\ Windows\ NT\ Servers,Node\ Vendor=Microsoft,metric_name=Disk\ Space\ Utilization metric_value=0.69751 1546062000000000000\nnps,Component\ Name=E\:\\ Label\:DB\ Serial\ Number\ 51646c8b,Component\ Type=DISK,Node\ Name=f-lon21-wmemstr.testsystem.ie,Node\ Location=Labenv,N..."

The offset 61 looks pretty innocent, no special characters in it. Besides, it's not very clear whether powerhsell output should be checked, or the line in the telegraf log.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with removing the spaces from your keys and values. The influx line protocol uses a space to denote the separation between metric name/tags and actual stat values.